# Is it possible to subscribe to a public EventHandler in a class generated by a private constructor where an interface is returned?

Tags: c#

I have a public class with a public `EventHandler` delegate definition but a private constructor. The class is created using a static method and I don't know if or how I could subscribe to it without exposing a public constructor.

The example below shows `ISomeService` returned from the static method `UsingHttpClient`. So the class is instantiated but since the interface is returned and not the class instance there is no 'handle' to use to call `someInstance.SomeEvent += OnSomeEvent`.

```
public class SomeService
{
    public EventHandler<bool> SomeEvent;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    private SomeService(HttpClient httpclient) => _httpClient = httpClient;

    public static ISomeService UsingHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient) => new SomeService(httpClient);

    //...some other code invoking SomeEvent
}
```

I have tried creating a method to return the EventHandler but this is obviously wrong and results in an error: `public EventHandler<bool> GetBusyEvent => BusyEvent;`.

I have also tried listing the `EventHandler` delegate in the `ISomeService` interface but this gives the error in VS2019: "Interfaces cannot contain instance fields".

Is this even possible? I don't want to redesign the class with a public constructor but I don't know of any other way.

Comment: There is no problem in having a private constructor. But `UsingHttpClient()` should be a static method so you can call it without an instance of `SomeService`. Please [edit] your question with a more detailed description of your problem, the error message(s) you get and the source code related to that error message.

Comment: Ya, sorry I forgot to copy in `static` when I wrote it in notepad. I'll add more detail shortly. The actual code is substantially more detailed than this and I was scolded last time for including too much detail.

Comment: Without [MCVE] of code that causes error it is very hard to know what your problem is... Also " listing the EventHandler delegate in the ISomeService interface but this isn't allowed" is strange - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-interface-events. `SomeService  service = getItSomehow(); service.SomeEvent += a => {};` should work perfectly fine irrespective of type of constructor...

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. To access a public instance member, i.e. `SomeEvent`, you must have a reference to an instance of the object. But this instance can be provided in any way you like. There's no requirement that the _constructor_ be public. The instance could be a singleton or returned by a factory method, for example. And indeed, you have what appears to be a factory-like method, `UsingHttpClient()`. What's wrong with using the instance that returns?

Comment: @PeterDuniho the issue here is that `ISomeService` interface is returned, not an instance of the class. Now I could be wrong here which is why I ask. I'm returning an interface which has no definition for the `EventHandler` declaration. If you have a suggestion, post an answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `SomeService` is not returned. The example above clearly shows the interface is returned.

Comment: The solution IS to declare your event in the interface. In what way is it not allowed?

Comment: @JasperKent, Visual studio gives "Interfaces cannot contain instance fields"

Comment: Did you remember the event keyword when you put it in the interface?

Comment: @JasperKent, I noticed that from the link Alexei posted just now. I'm playing with it a bit here. It doesn't throw any errors anymore but that looks to be the answer. I need to do some reading as to what the `event` keyword does in this case...

Comment: Argh! Just noticed you don't have the event keyword on your class either. So your class simply has a public field called SomeEvent, which wont' be implementing the event that you've now declared in the interface. You wan't the keyword event in both.

Comment: @JasperKent that was it. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between an event and a delegate in C# is quite a tricky one to explain.

A delegate is a type that can contain a list of functions matching the specification. So

```
public EventHandler<bool> SomeEvent;
```

declares a public field `SomeEvent`.

Client code could add functions to this list and remove them, both of which are reasonable things to do. But client code could also *invoke* the functions in the list, which we don't want. That should be the job of the `SomeService` class.

So effectively we want add and remove (+= and -=) to be public, but invocation to be private.

This is precisely what the event keyword does.

```
public event EventHandler<bool> SomeEvent;
```

The above code actually creates *three* elements in the class:

1. A private field of type EventHandler
2. A public method called add_SomeEvent
3. A public method called remove_SomeEvent

Calling SomeEvent+= or SomeEvent-= maps on to these last two.

Here's what it looks like in ILDASM:

[image: ILDASM for an event]

Now, an interface can only specify methods (a property being a pair of methods), so when we declare an event in an interface, it means that a class implementing the interface must provide the add and remove methods (2 and 3 above). It does not actually require that the class provides the private field.

However, the most common way to implement an event from an interface is to declare it in the same way, which gives us the two methods *and* the field, which is bonus (as far as the interface is concerned).

It is possible (though not all that common) to manually implement an event, i.e. two write the add and remove methods for ourselves and to store the the actual delegate in some way other than a simple field. This is typically done either to save memory when there are a large number of events in a class, or to forward an event to be managed by a different event in another class.

Comment: Excellent answer! The fix was this, plus the modification to the interface.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to an `ISomeService` that you know is a `SomeService`, then you can cast it.

Eg

```
ISomeService svc = SomeService.UsingHttpClient(client);
if (svc is SomeService ss)
{
    ss.SomeEvent += (s,a) =>
    {
        //whatever
    };
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. I'll give it a try but I think Alexei's mention about declaring the `EventHandler` with the `event` keyword in the interface definition might be the answer here.

Comment: If all ISomeService implementations will support the event, then yes.